# Conflicting Constraints: top + 8

Tags: interface-builder

I have an ImageView within a Stack View. When I try to add some space to the surrounding stack view with constraints I get:
Conflicting Constraints:

```
Image View.top = top + 8
top = Image View.top
```

This is the only constraint I have within this Stack View.
I have no idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add Constraints concerning the direction of you UIStackView.
There is an Spacing Attribute of the UIStackView for this.

For example:
In an Vertical UIStackView, if are not able to establish constraints between the Bottom of your first Item in the UIStackView and the Top of the Second Item.

Solution:
Let Interface Builder do the work for you by using the Spacing attribute of UIStackView.